# Persisting log-in with React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, authentication, persistent, mern

so, I'm currently working on a MERN app that successfully saves JWT tokens via library **localstorage**, surviving any refresh attempts (new users show up in the database, etc, the backend is all working as intended).

The issue is, the frontend React app has `'user'` set to `'null'` by default in the container's state, so that incongruency is what keeps logging users upon out upon re-rendering despite the JWT. I've been stuck on this for over a day now, have tried implementing a variety of possible solutions, have received help from my instructors, etc, nothing is achieving the desired result- does anyone have any advice?

I have attached the code from my container for reference (excuse the messiness, I'm in the middle of being too frustrated with this whole thing to do much about that), Furthermore I also got a bunch of other components and files that interact with my container in some way or other, won't attach them now but if anyone feels that the extra context is needed in order to help then I will do so. Thank you!

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { getItems } from "../services/items";
import Routes from "../routes";
import Header from "../screens/Header";
import { verifyToken } from '../services/auth'

export default class Container extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      user: null,
      items: [],
      isLoggedIn: false
    };
  }

  async componentDidMount() {
    // const user = await verifyToken();
    // if (user) {
    try {
      const items = await getItems();
      this.setState({
        items,
        isLoggedIn: true
      });
    }
    catch (err) {
      console.error(err);
    }
  }


  addItem = item =>
    this.setState({
      items: [item, ...this.state.items]
    });

  editItem = (itemId, item) => {
    const updateIndex = this.state.items.findIndex(
      element => element._id === itemId
    ),
      items = [...this.state.items];
    items[updateIndex] = item;
    this.setState({
      items
    });
  };

  destroyItem = item => {
    const destroyIndex = this.state.items.findIndex(
      element => element._id === item._id
    ),
      items = [...this.state.items];
    if (destroyIndex > -1) {
      items.splice(destroyIndex, 1);
      this.setState({
        items
      });
    }
  };

  setUser = user => this.setState({ user });

  //verifyUser = user => (localStorage.getItem('token')) ? this.setState({ user, isLoggedIn: true }) : null

  clearUser = () => this.setState({ user: null });

  render() {
    // const token = localStorage.getItem('token');
    // console.log(token)
    const { user, items } = this.state;
    return (
      <div className="container-landing">
        <Header user={user} />
        <main className="container">
          <Routes
            items={items}
            user={user}
            setUser={this.setUser}
            addItem={this.addItem}
            editItem={this.editItem}
            destroyItem={this.destroyItem}
            clearUser={this.clearUser}
          //verifyUser={this.verifyUser}
          />
        </main>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I dont see the code where user is given? verifyUser receives a user object where exactly is this passed along? Possibly thr failure is in setting/getting JWT correctly either in localstorage or in db or both. So the code related to these functions should be posted as well. This code does not seem to have any issues but code is missing

Comment: plus you would want to uncomment `verifyToken` because at the moment it looks like the user would get logged in when `Container` mounts becuase you are setting `isLoggedIn: true` without any checks whatsoever